# Mini PC - low power cunsumption - fanless - running 24*7 - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bits

Tags: linux, mini-pc

I'm looking for a mini PC to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bits version with a web server (LAMP) on it. The criterias would be, in order of importance:

- Low power cunsumption
  the mini pc will be running 24*7
- Fanless
  the idea is to have as few movable parts as possible and as low noise as possible
- support Linux and Windows
  it will be running latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits version, with a web server running on it (Apache/MySQL/PHP). But I want to be able to switch to Windows 7/8/10 if I want to.
- CPU
  a cpu that is **low power cunsumption** and permits to run smoothly with the given starting config (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + Web Server)
- RAM
  support minimum 16 GB RAM
- HardDrive
  support for 2 internal HD (1 SSD drive >= 64 GB and 1 SATA >= 2TB)
  OS will be on SSD and data will be on SATA
- Network
  minimum  1 Ethernet + 1 Wifi
- Ports
  usual ports : 4 USB (mix of 2.0 and 3.0), 1 HDMI, 1 VGA, 1 audio

To give a usage idea, it would be used by a small office (<= 10 users) as office web server.
If you have a price range for such config I take it too!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not totally fanless, but Intel NUCs are pretty good for what you want. They aren't that expensive and have pretty good performance and upgradeability and they are small.

For example [this one](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc7i5bnh.html) has maximum memory size of 32 GB, M.2 and 2.5" drive bays, 4 USBs. It doesn't have VGA though, instead you get HDMI 2.0.

There is much more of them [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits.html), or you can even build your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at a company called Logic Supply. They make an array of pretty decent mini-pc fanless computers. They ask a premium for more memory though, most of their older model's top out at 8GB of ram and I found several that advertise a maximum of 32GB of RAM but wouldn't let you configure more than 16GB.

[This one](https://www.logicsupply.com/ml600g-10/) offers ECC memory, but their online configuration tool only allows up to 8GB of RAM, so you'd either need to talk with them directly or modify it yourself (which might void your warranty, not sure). Look around though, Logic Supply has a lot of models and each model has a lot of configuration options. If you don't see what you want, call them up and ask, they gave me good service.

Another possible contender is the [Compulab Airtop](http://airtop-pc.com/airtop/). It comes in several different models, including one intended for server use with ECC memory and RAID.

There aren't very many companies making computers without fans right now. At a previous job I was looking for small fanless PCs for a factory floor and eventually stumbled into Logic Supply. I left before we'd done more than put a few units out for evaluation, but they ran flawlessly 24-7 for the 6months or so before I left. I had no problems with their sales and support guys either.

I've never had a compulab computer, but the specs look good and its gotten some good reviews. Thought it was worth the comparison anyway!

Do your research, and good luck!